# Data is displaying on the console but not effecting the in android listview

Tags: android, json, sockets, listview

I am developing a socket based app. I am reading the data and converting into JSON and then displaying in List-view.

socket data reading is as follows :

```
   public String clientReceive(int check) {
    try {

        if (s != null) {
            while (s.isConnected()) {
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        s.getInputStream()));
                int nRead;
                char[] data = new char[8192];

                String decoded = "";
                String symbs = "";
                while ((nRead = in.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                    decoded = new String(data, 0, nRead);
                    decoded = new String(decoded.getBytes(),"UTF-8");
                        return decoded;

            }   
        }   

    } catch (SocketException e) {

    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    // return null;
    return null;
}
```

Asyn Task doInBackgroung method and postExecute methods are:

```
           @Override
    protected ArrayList<User> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //isCycleQuit=false;

        for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
            if (isCancelled()) {
                System.out.println("**** All timers killed ***");
                break;
            }
        }
        JSONmessage += client.clientReceive(1);
        message=JSONmessage;
        JSONmessage="";
        //System.out.println("MESSAGE Socket::" + message);

        return null;
    }

           protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<User> result) {
        if (!message.contains("null")) {
            printJson();
            // updateList();
            displayView();
        }
            }
```

I am displaying the data using the display view method.

```
public void displayView() {
    try {
        if (!marketWatch.equalsIgnoreCase("custom")) {
            if (!swapBool)
                adb = new RSSListAdaptor(DefaultMarketWatch.this,
                        R.layout.rssitemview, list);
            else {
                adb = new RSSListAdaptor(DefaultMarketWatch.this,
                        R.layout.arabiclist, list);
            }
        } else {
            if (!swapBool)
                adb = new RSSListAdaptor(DefaultMarketWatch.this,
                        R.layout.customlayout, list);
            else {
                adb = new RSSListAdaptor(DefaultMarketWatch.this,
                        R.layout.ar_customlayout, list);
            }
        }
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I need to read the data fro each second and display. I can  see the listview most of the times. but some times data is displaying on the console. But not updating the UI and keep leading.

where I went wrong. kindly please help.

Thanks.

Comment: is there any exception occured? and where are you printing the data to the console?

Comment: I fond no exceptions and I am printing the data on the console from the doInBackground() method

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23113164/kill-all-asynctask-tasks-in-android/23114036?noredirect=1#23114036 my previous post how I am reading the data for each second.Please refer. Thanks

Comment: try to check the data again in the displayView() function